# Where do I find Observable in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have VS2010 RTM installed and I want to add a reference to the Reactive Framework, I've looked for system.CoreEx and system.Reactive and they are not there.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download and install the Rx assemblies for .Net v4.0, since Rx is not yet released:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Another alternative, which is shipping, is the `Observable` module in F#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370313(VS.100).aspx

EDIT - Rx 2.0 is released now, so you might feel better about taking a dependency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610.

Answer (score 1):

Only the IObservable<T> and IObserver<T> interfaces are in the .NET v4.0 framework. The Rx operators and related classes are in the download pointed out by codekaizen.

Answer (score 0):

Codekaizen's response was best answer until Microsoft put Rx to open source: [Reactive Extensions (Rx) is now Open Source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReactiveExtensionsRxIsNowOpenSource.aspx)